# Modules Not Being Found

Tags: d3.js, error-handling, papaparse

I keep getting the error "cannot find module papaparse" for the first code and "cannot find module d3 on the second code block. I have them installed and can see the versions 5.4.1 for papa and 7.8.5 for d3? Why can't they be found. I feel like it has to be a simple issue I'm overlooking. I feel like solving one will solve the other. Maybe I'm wrong but any help is appreciated.

Code with papaparse issue:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Table, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody, Paper, TableSortLabel } from '@mui/material';
import { readString } from 'papaparse';
import { orderBy } from 'lodash';


function TableCreate() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState([]);
  const [sortConfig, setSortConfig] = useState({ key: null, direction: 'asc' });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/dummyDataCSV.csv');
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      const result = await reader.read();
      const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
      const csv = decoder.decode(result.value);
      const parsedData = readString(csv).data;
      setData(parsedData);
      setSortedData(parsedData.slice(1)); // Skip the header row
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleSort = (column) => {
    let direction = 'asc';
    if (sortConfig.key === column && sortConfig.direction === 'asc') {
      direction = 'desc';
    }
    setSortConfig({ key: column, direction });
    setSortedData(orderBy(sortedData, [column], [direction]));
  };

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {data.length > 0 && data[0].map((header, index) => (
              <TableCell key={index}>
                <TableSortLabel
                  active={sortConfig.key === index}
                  direction={sortConfig.key === index ? sortConfig.direction : 'asc'}
                  onClick={() => handleSort(index)}
                >
                  {header}
                </TableSortLabel>
              </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {sortedData.map((row, rowIndex) => (
            <TableRow key={rowIndex}>
              {row.map((cell, cellIndex) => (
                <TableCell key={cellIndex}>{cell}</TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}

export default TableCreate;
```

And for the second group of code for d3:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody } from '@mui/material';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import * as d3 from "d3";

function TableTestD3() {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    d3.csv("dummyDataCSV.csv").then((data) => {
      setTableData(data);
    });
  }, []);

  const headers = tableData.length > 0 ? Object.keys(tableData[0]) : [];

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {headers.map((header) => (
              <TableCell align="center" key={header}>{header}</TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {tableData.map((row, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index}>
              {headers.map((header) => (
                <TableCell align="center" key={header}>{row[header]}</TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}

export default TableTestD3;
```

I was asked to see my packages.JSON here it is:

```
{
  "name": "material-dashboard-2-pro-react",
  "version": "2.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Creative Tim",
  "license": "See license in https://www.creative-tim.com/license",
  "description": "React version of Material Dashboard 2 PRO by Creative Tim",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-material-dashboard-pro-react/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-material-dashboard-pro-react.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@asseinfo/react-kanban": "2.2.0",
    "@emotion/cache": "11.10.8",
    "@emotion/react": "11.10.8",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.10.8",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "6.1.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "5.12.3",
    "@react-jvectormap/core": "1.0.4",
    "@react-jvectormap/world": "1.1.2",
    "chart.js": "4.3.0",
    "chroma-js": "2.4.2",
    "d3": "^7.8.5",
    "draft-convert": "^2.1.13",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "dropzone": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "flatpickr": "4.6.13",
    "formik": "2.2.9",
    "html-react-parser": "3.0.16",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.15.0",
    "react-flatpickr": "3.10.13",
    "react-github-btn": "1.4.0",
    "react-images-viewer": "1.7.1",
    "react-router-dom": "6.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-table": "7.8.0",
    "stylis": "4.1.4",
    "stylis-plugin-rtl": "2.1.1",
    "uuid": "9.0.0",
    "yup": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.39.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.8"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "svgo": "3.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed it already, It could be your TS server not able to detect it. Try restarting the TS server.

If you're using VS Code you can follow these steps:

1. Open the file in which you're getting this error.
2. Now open command palette by clicking <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd + Shift + P</kbd>.
3. Search `Restart TS Server`.
4. Wait for it to restart and see if it resolves your error or not.

If you're still getting the error, try these steps:

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder.
2. Reinstall dependencies by using `npm install` or `yarn` command.
3. Wait for the installation and check again if it resolves your error.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately it did not alleviate my issue.

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file by editing the question?

Comment: It looks like you have missing `types` dependencies. Try installing related types for `d3` or `papaparse`. Use this command `npm install -D @types/d3` or `yarn add -D @types/d3`. It should fix `d3` error.

Comment: i gave up on papaparse, focus on D3 and that did not fix it. Getting the same D3 error.